# Cloudberry bare metal recovery network share access

Tags: backup, network-attached-storage, disaster-recovery

I am doing a test backup and restore with cloudberry and running into an issue.

My server is a Windows server 2016 version, running on vmware esxi.  I have used Cloudberry to backup to a share folder on a local NAS (synology).  The share folder is secured with a local user account on the NAS.  I completed a full image backup and it was successful.  I then used the "make a bootable USB" tool to make an ISO for recovery.  I did this from the same 2106 server so that it would grab its drivers and settings.

I want to recover to a Virtual machine in VMWare Workstation for my test.  I setup my VM to have similar hardware as the original server and more than enough hard drive space.  I mount and boot the recovery ISO and pull up a command prompt to test network connectivity.  I can ping both the NAS and google.  But for some reason it doesnt see the backup that was stored on the NAS.  When I open the network credentials > Add/Edit Network Path and check the path to the folder on the NAS, its there and correct, but the "TEST" fails saying the path doesn't exist.

For some reason the Cloudberry recovery environment cant authenticate to the NAS and see the files.

Any help would be great, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to restore to VMWare is restore your image as a virtual disk of VMWare format (VMDK), create new machine via VMWare console and attach this disk.

With recovery ISO it should also work, problem might be in case your VM doesn't receive IP address from DHCP. Once you've boot from ISO, launch CMD and check your current IP address or define it manually in case of zero address.

One of two solutions for sure will work, you just need a bit of Good luck!)